# How to update list in catch block

Tags: javascript

I have a small custom polyfill for Promise.all and while trying to execute it I see that update of array(errorList) in catch block is not working. Can someone please help me understand what am I missing.

```
Promise.customAll = function (promisesList) {
  let errorList = [];
  let resultList = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    promisesList.forEach(async (promise, index) => {
      try {
        let result = await promise;
        resultList[index] = (result);
      } catch (err) {
        errorList.push(err);
      }
    });

    if (errorList.length) {
      reject(errorList);
    } else {
      resolve(resultList);
    }
  });
};
```

Here is how I am using it. For above code I am expecting my promise tp go to catch block but its going to then block and printing `[ 'FirstPromise', <1 empty item>, '3rd Promise' ]`

```
Promise.customAll([Promise.resolve("FirstPromise"), Promise.reject("Error in 2nd Promise"), Promise.resolve("3rd Promise")])
  .then((val) => {
    console.log(val);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: You have to wait until all promises resolve first, so wrap the forEach in a promise and call the resolve function when the index is the length minus one after the current promise resolves

Comment: I don’t think this would give the right behavior, actually

Comment: You are right again, it won't work if promise is not rejected or resolved in sequence, but should work for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Promise.customAll = function (promisesList) {
  let errorList = [];
  let resultList = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    promisesList.forEach(async (promise, index) => {
      try {
        let result = await promise;
        resultList[index] = result;

        if (index === promisesList.length - 1) {
          if (errorList.length) {
            reject(errorList);
          } else {
            resolve(resultList);
          }
        }
      } catch (err) {
        errorList.push(err);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

As suggested by @youdateme, moved my logic in forEach callback as its async that solved the issue.